# change value of column for duplicate rows based on column values, except if column value is specified

Tags: pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataset with columns A,B,C,D,E. I want to do 3 things:
Input :

```
A           B           C   D   E
ARN-0098    50732536    61  FD  0
ARN-0098    50732536    61  ABC 10456
ARN-0098    65363672    61  FD  10447
ARN-0098    65363672    61  ABC 10447
ARN-0098    65363672    61  FD  10447
ARN-0098    65363672    61  FD  10447
ARN-0098    55297611    61  ABC 10424
ARN-0098    55297611    61  FD  10424
ARN-0098    55297611    61  FD  10424
ARN-0098    57039959    61  FD  10434
ARN-0098    57039959    61  FD  10434
ARN-0098    58224047    61  FD  10429
ARN-0098    58224047    61  FD  10429
ARN-0098    59780609    61  ABC 10423
ARN-0098    59780609    61  ABC 10423
ARN-0098    59780609    61  FD  10423
```

First, check for duplicate rows based on columns A,B,C,E.
Second, for each group of duplicates, if the first unique row has D = 'ABC', then I need to set E value to 0. Then, i need to set E value of every other duplicate row to 0, so that for every group of rows i only have 1 row with a unique E value and the rest of the rows are 0.
Then, I need to add a column to see which of the E values have been changed.
Output:

```
A                 B             C            D      E   REMARKS
ARN-0098        50734894        61      FD      0       FALSE
ARN-0098        50732536        61      ABC     10456   FALSE
ARN-0098        65363672        61      FD      10447   FALSE
ARN-0098        65363672        61      ABC     0        TRUE
ARN-0098        65363672        61      FD      0        TRUE
ARN-0098        65363672        61      FD      0        TRUE
ARN-0098        55297611        61      ABC     0        TRUE
ARN-0098        55297611        61      FD      10424   FALSE
ARN-0098        55297611        61      FD      0        TRUE
ARN-0098        57039959        61      FD      10434   FALSE
ARN-0098        57039959        61      FD      0        TRUE
ARN-0098        58224047        61      FD      10429   FALSE
ARN-0098        58224047        61      FD      0        TRUE
ARN-0098        59780609        61      ABC     0        TRUE
ARN-0098        59780609        61      ABC     0        TRUE
ARN-0098        59780609        61      FD      10423   FALSE
```

I have edited my previous question because I did not fully explain my needs.

Comment: what happens if you have a group with only A?

Comment: all of them would be changed to 0

Comment: OK, then I'll swap my two answers to put the one you want on top

Comment: Let me try this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### approach #1: if A is alone, mark as duplicate

Alternatively, pre-filter A out, then run `duplicated` on this subset and merge the boolean masks with `|`:

```
m1 = df['Column D'].eq('A')
m2 = df[~m1].duplicated(subset=cols)

df.loc[m1|m2, 'Column E'] = 0
```

Output (with intermediates for clarity and some extra groups):

```
   Column A  Column B  Column C Column D  Column E     m1     m2  m1|m2
0         1         2         3        A         0   True    NaN   True
1         1         2         3        B       100  False  False  False
2         1         2         3        C         0  False   True   True
3         1         2         3        D         0  False   True   True
4         2         4         5        B       200  False  False  False
5         2         4         5        A         0   True    NaN   True
6         2         4         5        C         0  False   True   True
7         3         6         7        A         0   True    NaN   True
8         4         8         9        B       300  False  False  False
```

##### approach #2: if A is alone, don't mark as duplicate

You can add a flag based on the condition, then [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), then when you run [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) you'll keep as non-duplicate a non-A value in priority:

```
cols = ['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C', 'Column E']

m = (df.assign(flag=df['Column D'].eq('A'))
       .sort_values(by='flag')
       .duplicated(subset=cols)
    )

df.loc[m, 'Column E'] = 0
```

Output:

```
   Column A  Column B  Column C Column D  Column E
0         1         2         3        A         0
1         1         2         3        B       100
2         1         2         3        C         0
3         1         2         3        D         0
4         2         4         5        B       200
5         2         4         5        A         0
6         2         4         5        C         0
```

Intermediates (with the output of `duplicated` as a column for clarity):

```
   Column A  Column B  Column C Column D  Column E   flag  duplicated
1         1         2         3        B       100  False       False
2         1         2         3        C         0  False       False
3         1         2         3        D         0  False        True
4         2         4         5        B       200  False       False
6         2         4         5        C         0  False       False
0         1         2         3        A         0   True        True
5         2         4         5        A         0   True        True
```

Note that the two strategies will behave differently if you have a group with only A

Comment: @Smith I'm not sorting alphabetically, I'm sorting based on the boolean flag to have `True` after `False`. it would work even if `A` is `Z` or `B2`

Comment: yup, sorry, i just realised. Let me try this out! Thank you

Comment: @Smith also please answer my comment to your question, this will decide which of the two approaches is wanted

Comment: hi! how can i see which rows had the values of column E were changed?

Comment: @Smith you can add `df['changed'] = m1|m2`

Comment: @ mozway but there are rows where E value was already 0. How do I make sure df['changed'] is True only for those rows where E was not 0 to begin with and was changed to 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
duplicates = df.duplicated(subset=cols, keep=False)
first_instance_condition = (df['Column D'] != 'A') & ~duplicates
```

Comment: does this account for changing column E to 0 in case of duplicates?

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**